# Using new on a function doesn't work unless merged with an interface. Why?

Tags: typescript

This is all assuming `noImplicityAny` is set to `true`.

Given this:

```
function Bar() {
    this.f = 100;
}
```

this doesn't work:

`let x = new Bar();`

The error you get is:

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

OK, I guess that kind of makes sense.

However, if I add an interface to the mix, it works fine:

```
interface Bar { 
     f: number;
}

function Bar() {
    this.f = 100;
}

let x = new Bar();
console.log(x.f);
```

When hovering over `Bar` you see this as the type:

`interface Bar function Bar(): void`

So I get that there's some merging going on. I'm just unclear as to why this works now? What exactly is this new merged type, and why is the return type of the `Bar()` function no longer implied to be `any`?

Comment: Just a guess, but the interface means that the new object can't be of 'any' type.  Still a great question, I want to know more :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're experiencing is [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in TypeScript. Basically if two entities have same declared name, TypeScript merges them together into a single entity. This allows you to do some powerful things like writing declarations and interfaces for 3rd party JavaScript libraries to make them type aware.

In your first example, the compiler knows the return type of `Bar()`, which is `void`. It doesn't however know what constructor returns so `new Bar()` is assumed to be `any`.

But when you declare an interface of the same name, the compiler merges the `interface Bar` with `function Bar()`, and the interface now defines a *shape* which resembles the function, so the compiler picks it up as the type of `new Bar()`. Note that type of `Bar()` still stays `void`.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, why does the existence of the interface change the return type of the `new Bar()`?

Comment: The interface `Bar` defines a _shape_ for the function `Bar`, which the compiler previously couldn't find. When you declare the interface, the compiler now knows what is the shape, hence type of `new Bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript type system does know this is a new-able constructor function.

Instead of a function and an interface, you can define it as a single class.

```
class Bar {
  f = 100;
} 

let x = new Bar();
console.log(x.f);
```

If you are targeting es5 the generated code will essentially be the same as the constructor function in your question.